# How to solve time-dependent Schrodinger equation and plot trajectory on Bloch sphere?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computing, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

Let's say I have a $2 \times 2$ Hamiltonian that I am solving using the time-dependent Schrodinger equation:
$$
i \frac{d}{dt} |{\Phi}\rangle=H|{\Phi}\rangle.\tag{1}
$$
Consider a generic Hamiltonian
$$
H = \begin{bmatrix}
h_1 & h_2\tag{2} \\
h_3 & h_4\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
$|{\Phi}\rangle$ takes the general form with complex coefficients $(a,b)^T$ (a column vector). Then, given some initial conditions (such as $a(0)=0,b(0)=1$), I can solve the following system of equations resulting from the Schrodinger equation above:
$$
\begin{align}\tag{3}
i \dot{a}&=a h_1 + b h_2\\
i\dot{b}&=a h_3 + b h_4,\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
where the overhead dot denotes a time-derivative.

This can give me the coefficients $a,b$ at each time $t$. However, I now want to plot this trajectory on the [Bloch sphere](https://medium.com/quantum-untangled/quantum-states-and-the-bloch-sphere-9f3c0c445ea3), a convenient tool for visualizing 2-state systems. All 2-state Hermitian systems may be mapped to this tool, which in its simplest form corresponds to a spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ particle in an effective magnetic field.

If $|{\Phi}\rangle$ can be written in the following basis:
$$
|{\Phi}\rangle=a |0\rangle + b|1\rangle,\tag{5}
$$
(corresponding to the same coefficients $a,b$ found earlier), we can equivalently write
$$
|{\Phi}\rangle=\cos\left({\frac{\theta}{2}}\right) |0\rangle + \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) e^{i\phi}|1\rangle,\tag{6}
$$
where $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the polar and azimuthal angles in spherical coordinates.

How do I plot the trajectory of the state, say, from $t=0$ to $t=1$?
If I solve $a=\cos\left({\frac{\theta}{2}}\right) $ and $b=\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) e^{i\phi}$, the resulting $\theta,\phi$ are going to be complex angles in general. These cannot be plotted on a sphere as they are not real values. Where did I go wrong in my understanding?

What I want to achieve is similar to the animation in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243625/schr%C3%B6dinger-equation-on-the-bloch-sphere). Even in their case, you end up with complex $|\Phi\rangle$. I do not get how we can plot such complex angles.

Thank you.

Comment: QuTip has a section on doing this, see: https://qutip.org/docs/4.1/guide/guide-bloch.html

Comment: @EverydayFoolish, thanks. I did find that earlier, and went tried to find how they did this using their GitHub source code. But I was not successful with the insufficient skills I have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The angles $\phi$ and $\theta$ ***never*** contain a non-zero imaginary part (they are always purely real numbers). The general solution to Eq. 1 is:

$$
\tag{1}
|\Phi(t)\rangle = e^{-\textrm{i}H t} | \Phi(0)\rangle.
$$

This can be written as:

$$
\tag{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
a(t) \\
b(t)
\end{bmatrix} = U
\begin{bmatrix}
a(0) \\
b(0)
\end{bmatrix} 
.
$$

where the unitary matrix $U$ is just the matrix exponential in Eq. 1. The general expression for a 2x2 unitary matrix is:

$$\tag{3}
U = \begin{bmatrix}
 c & d \\
 -e^{i\varphi} d^* & e^{i\varphi} c^* \\
\end{bmatrix},
\qquad
\left| c \right|^2 + \left| d \right|^2 = 1.
$$

You now have the solution:

$$
\tag{4}
\begin{bmatrix}
a(t) \\
b(t)
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
c\cdot a(0) + d\cdot b(0)\\
 -e^{i\varphi} d^*\cdot a(0) + e^{i\varphi} c^* \cdot b(0)
\end{bmatrix} 
.
$$

In your case, $a(0) = 0$ and $b(0) = 1$, so its even simpler:

\begin{align}
\tag{5}
\begin{bmatrix}
a(t) \\
b(t)
\end{bmatrix} &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
 d\\
  e^{i\varphi} c^* 
\end{bmatrix} 
\\
&=d(t)|0\rangle +   e^{i\varphi} c^*(t)|1\rangle.\tag{6}
\end{align}

If you recall the [polar form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Modulus_and_argument) of a complex number, the angle (or "phase") is always a real number, and the same is true here.

Often Eq. 3 is expressed as in Eq. 2.31 of [this set of PDF lecture notes](http://theory.caltech.edu/%7Epreskill/ph219/chap2_15.pdf) by John Preskill (but the same formula will be found in almost every first year course on quantum information theory and many advanced NMR courses):

[image]

Here $\hat{n}$ is a unit vector with three components and $\vec{\mathbf{\sigma}}$ is a vector containing three elements: $\sigma_x$, $\sigma_y$ and $\sigma_z$. Note also that any Hermitian 2x2 matrix can be decomposed in terms of the identity $I$ and the three elements of $\vec{\sigma}$. Since $\textrm{i}\sigma_y$ will be real, the only imaginary numbers will appear from $\textrm{i}\sigma_x$ and $\textrm{i}\sigma_z$, for which in both cases you can factor out $e^{\textrm{i}\phi}$, especially since when $\phi=\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have $e^{\textrm{i}\phi} = \textrm{i}$.

Comment: I guess chapter 2 of Eberly and Allen has a good section on this, and about the intuition for understanding two-level system(TLS) dynamics on bloch sphere.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am still having trouble understanding what's going on. 1) I hope to do this without rewriting H in terms of Pauli matrices (I am working with several models, for which this will take a lot of time). Is this possible? 2) Is my approach of time-evolving the Schro. eq. not feasible? 3) I chose U = exp(-i H(t) t). But this does not take the form of eq. (4) numerically, and gives me two different $\phi$.

Comment: 4) How do I get the angles from eq. (4) for general initial conditions? Do I just use eq. (6) from my post? But then I get complex angles again. Or, for the case in eq. (6) in your post, using polar angles, $d(t)$ and $e^{i\phi}c^{*}(t)$ are complex and give $\cos(\phi_1)+i \sin(\phi_1)$ and $\cos(\phi_2)+i \sin(\phi_2)$ respectively. I cannot see how this gives $\theta$ and $\phi$ for the sphere. I am terribly sorry I've misunderstood.

Comment: If you are limiting yourself to TLS, then you can just follow expectation values of the pauli matrices and you can just plot $\langle\vec{S
}(t)\rangle$ or $\frac{\hbar}{2} \left( \langle\sigma_{x}(t)\rangle,\langle\sigma_{y}(t)\rangle,\langle\sigma_{z}(t)\rangle\right) $ in 3D space, where your axes would be $\vec{S_{x}}, \vec{S_{y}}, \vec{S_{z}}$

Comment: Also, to add another point, your $\phi$ and $\theta$ at any given moment in time, say $t$, would be the solid angle and polar angle of the vector $\langle \vec{S}(t)\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you @EverydayFoolish. I saw something similar in eq 2.62 of A Short Course on Topological Insulators (https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02295), but wasn't sure of the validity here because it did not involve explicit time evolution via the TDSE or rotation operator. I guess it makes sense now.

Comment: @EverydayFoolish I don't mind if you write another answer! Comments are temporary and can often be deleted without notification.

Comment: @NikeDattani I think I figured it out! I think I can achieve this using the solution to the TDSE by fixing the gauge such that the first component of the eigenvector, the coefficient $a$, is real!